# How do I set a local hosting port for my gradle project with Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

How do I set a local hosting port for my gradle project with Intellij?

I'm trying to run a Gradle project with bootstrap in the intelliJ IDE. 
Upon running it i get the fallowing error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I have looked into what would be listening on that port and how to kill it seemed like more trouble than it's worth. This is what I tried.:

[image: This is what I tried.]

I'm looking for how to change the port that my project uses. I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1 and Gradle 3.4.1. most solutions I've seen employ a BuildConfig.groovy file but I don't believe my project has any such file.

Any way to get around the hosting problem would be great but right now I'm thinking changing the default port is the best way.

Comment: `Gradle project with bootstrap in the intelliJ IDE` what exactly is that? What kind of server are you running? Is it spring boot application?

Comment: Yeah, it's a spring boot web application. I'm not running a server, I just want to locally run the project for testing

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, you are running a Spring Boot application and you want to change the server port. You are running a server, even if you want to run the application locally for testing. Spring Boot comes with a embedded Tomcat or Jetty.

You can change the port by changing the application property `server.port`. You can pass it on command-line:

`--server.port=8090`

or set it in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8090
```

or `application.yml`

```
server:
    port: 8090
```

[See the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still am not sure what to do. I don't have the application.properties file of the application.yml file. I also don't know how to use the command-line to give commands to a specific application.

Comment: So how do you build and run the application?